# Enable ring/silent switch with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, recording, avaudiosession

How do I make physical ring/silent switch work again when I want to play and record audio at the same time using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord? I just cannot find an answer to that anywhere.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If I set audio session like this:
  AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
The switch no longer mutes my playback. I would like to override this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord is designed for audio-centric apps, where the purpose of the app is to play music.  When this category is set, audio will not be silenced by the mute switch or the screen lock.  VOIP apps and music apps desire this behavior.

If you want audio to be silenced by the mute switch, you'll need to switch the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient or AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient when not recording.

If you have access to the WWDC developer videos, I'd suggest watching "WWDC 2010 session 412 Audio Development for iPhone OS part 1".

Comment: I guessing that what I would like to do is simply not possible. Oh well, the enjoyments of iOS