# iOS - Detecting Silent Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, silent

I need to detect if the phone is in silent mode or not. I found [old way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008063/ios-9-detect-silent-mode) and [new way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105022/ios-9-how-to-detect-silent-mode) (playing an .caf file) but none of them worked correctly. Old way uses deprecated tools and new way always give "no" in both cases (silent mode and not).

At this point, can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: see  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284722/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-ios-device-is-in-silent-mode-or-not

Comment: You can find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect iphone is on silent mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This is in Swift but does not matter, i tried its Objective-C version and not get a good result.

Comment: @sschunaraThis answer uses the same methods of old way i mentioned. They are all deprecated and not like other deprecaed methods, these don't work correctly.

Comment: @IOS_DEV Again, audiosessionsinitalize is deprecated and these suggestions not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution and let me know if it works for you :

```
 -(BOOL)silenced {
     #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
         // return NO in simulator. Code causes crashes for some reason.
         return NO;
     #endif

    CFStringRef state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
    if(CFStringGetLength(state) > 0)
            return NO;
    else
            return YES;

    }
```

Comment: No this solution is just like old way and not working because as i told a lot of times, AudioSessionInitialize and getProperty methods are all deprecated. In both way (silent or not) it returns NO.